How to Introduce flexibility into a JavaFXML TreeTableView
The issue is not being able to introduce sufficient flexibility to render a TreeTableView when the sources of data required for the view are not known before the program is run. My objective is to be able to list all secondary storage devices attached to a PC. So far I have followed suggestions on this board and some other tutorials for implementing a TreeTableView. The suggestions usually follow this approach:
public class HelloController implements Initializable {
   
  @FXML private TreeTableView<String> mytree;
  @FXML private TreeTableColumn<String, String> colFirst;
  // TreeItems and Parents
  TreeItem<String> parentA = new TreeItem<>("A");
  TreeItem<String> parentC = new TreeItem<>("C");
  TreeItem<String> item1_l2 = new TreeItem<>("Name_Item1_Level2");
  TreeItem<String> item2_l2 = new TreeItem<>("Name_Item2_Level2");
  TreeItem<String> item3_l2 = new TreeItem<>("Name_Item3_Level2");
   
  TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root");

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    parentA.getChildren().setAll(item1_l2, item2_l2, item3_l2);
    parentC.getChildren().setAll(item1_l2, item2_l2, item3_l2);
    root.getChildren().setAll(parentA, parentC);
    mytree.setRoot(root);

    colFirst.setCellValueFactory(
       (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String>param) -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getValue()));

  }  
}


The fxml is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxWidth="250.0" prefHeight="300.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="directorycopy.view.HelloController">
  <TreeTableView fx:id="mytree" prefHeight="250.0" prefWidth="300.0">
     <columns>
        <TreeTableColumn id="colFirst" fx:id="colFirst" prefWidth="200.0" text="First" />
     </columns>
  </TreeTableView>
</VBox>


The result is exactly as expected:

However I find that this approach is limited because one would not know what devices are attached and what drive letters are associated with the devices. So I have tried to find a way to address the issue by expanding the tutorial examples accordingly:
public class HelloController implements Initializable {
  @FXML private TreeTableView<String> mytree;
  @FXML private TreeTableColumn<String, String> colFirst;
  // TreeItems and Parents
  TreeItem<String> parentA = new TreeItem<>("A");
  TreeItem<String> item1_l1 = new TreeItem<>("Dir1A");
  TreeItem<String> item2_l1 = new TreeItem<>("Dir2A");
  TreeItem<String> item3_l1 = new TreeItem<>("Dir3A");
  
  TreeItem<String> parentB = new TreeItem<>("B");
  
  TreeItem<String> parentC = new TreeItem<>("C");
  TreeItem<String> item1_l2 = new TreeItem<>("Name_Item1_Level2");
  TreeItem<String> item2_l2 = new TreeItem<>("Name_Item2_Level2");
  TreeItem<String> item3_l2 = new TreeItem<>("Name_Item3_Level2");
  
  TreeItem<String> parentD = new TreeItem<>("D");
  TreeItem<String> parentE = new TreeItem<>("E");
  TreeItem<String> parentF = new TreeItem<>("F");
  TreeItem<String> parentG = new TreeItem<>("G");
  TreeItem<String> parentH = new TreeItem<>("H");
  TreeItem<String> parentI = new TreeItem<>("I");
  TreeItem<String> parentJ = new TreeItem<>("J");
  TreeItem<String> parentK = new TreeItem<>("K");
  // same for drives L thru Z
  
  TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("Root");

//  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
 
    File[] paths  = File.listRoots();
    for(File path:paths){
      if (path.toString().substring(0).equals("A")) {
        root.getChildren().set(0, parentA);
        parentA.getChildren().setAll(item1_l2, item2_l2, item3_l2);
      };
      if (path.toString().substring(0).equals("B")) {
        root.getChildren().set(0, parentB);
        parentA.getChildren().setAll(item1_l2, item2_l2, item3_l2);
      };
      if (path.toString().substring(0).equals("C")) {
        root.getChildren().set(0, parentC);
        parentC.getChildren().setAll(item1_l2, item2_l2, item3_l2);
      };
      // And do similar for the remaining 23 drives
    }
    mytree.setRoot(root);

    colFirst.setCellValueFactory(
       (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String>param) -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getValue()));

  }
}

I am trying to achieve the same result as shown above, with additional flexibility for handling the inknown devices and their drive letters. However, this renders the following, which is not what I am trying to achieve:

I would appreciate some help in discovering what I am doing wrong here.

I refined my spec to implement a TreeTableView and populate it with dynamic content. The content is the drives discovered on a windows file system and the first level directories under each drive. To find the drives and their directories I created an observable list of every drive and directory and called it srcdirlist:
ObservableList<String> srcdirlist = getSrcDirectories();
    //Find the file system drives.
    String [] dirletters = getDirLetterArray(srcdirlist);
    mytree.setRoot(root); 
driveList = FXCollections.observableArrayList    (getDirLetterArray(srcdirlist));
//  Create and name the parents under the root and set them under the root. 
    parents = new TreeItem[driveList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < driveList.size(); i++) {
      parents[i] = new TreeItem<>(driveList.get(i));
    }
    root.getChildren().setAll(parents); 

The next step was, for each drive, to iterate through the source directory list to find the content associated with each drive.  The integer dn is the drive number. If the source directory entry satisfies some basic criteria, for example, not being a file, it is added to an instance of treeItem, which is then added to the parent associated with the drive:
   int dn = 0;  
    TreeItem<String> treeItems;
    //Add records from the source directory list to instances of TreeItem and
    //add them to the parent associated with a drive contents.
    while (dn < dirletters.length) {
      int dirsize = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < srcdirlist.size(); i++) {
        if (dirletters[dn].equals(srcdirlist.get(i).substring(0,3))) {
          treeItems = new TreeItem<>(srcdirlist.get(i));  
          parents[dn].getChildren().add(treeItems);
          dirsize++;
        }
      }
      lastRec += dirsize - 1;
      dn++;
    }

This produced the following result. This satisfied my objective:


The complete listing for the solution is:
public class HelloController implements Initializable {
  @FXML private TreeTableView<String> mytree;
  @FXML private TreeTableColumn<String, String> colFirst;
  
  private int lastRec;
  private TreeItem<String>[] parents;
  private ObservableList<String> driveList;
  private TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>("/");
  
  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) { 
    ObservableList<String> srcdirlist = getSrcDirectories();
    //Find the file system drives.
    String [] dirletters = getDirLetterArray(srcdirlist);
    mytree.setRoot(root); 
//   An observable list being populated with the collection from getDirLetterArray()
    driveList = FXCollections.observableArrayList (getDirLetterArray(srcdirlist));
//  Create and name the parents under the root and set them under te root. 
    parents = new TreeItem[driveList.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < driveList.size(); i++) {
      parents[i] = new TreeItem<>(driveList.get(i));
    }
    root.getChildren().setAll(parents);
    
    //Iterate through each drive to find each drive content..
    int dn = 0;  
    TreeItem<String> treeItems;
    //Add records from the source directory list to instances of TreeItem and
    //add them to the parent associated with a drive contents.
    while (dn < dirletters.length) {
      int dirsize = 1;
      for (int i = 0; i < srcdirlist.size(); i++) {
        if (dirletters[dn].equals(srcdirlist.get(i).substring(0,3))) {
          treeItems = new TreeItem<>(srcdirlist.get(i));  
          parents[dn].getChildren().add(treeItems);
          dirsize++;
        }
      }
      lastRec += dirsize - 1;
      dn++;
    }
    colFirst.setCellValueFactory(
      (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String>param) -> new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getValue()));
  }
  
  /**
   * Scans a complete file system to get the directories on each drive. 
   * @return An observable list of the file system drives and directory names.
   */
  public ObservableList<String> getSrcDirectories() {
    ObservableList<String> srcdirlist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    String rootpath;
    File[] drivefiles = File.listRoots();
    if (drivefiles != null && drivefiles.length > 0) {
      for (File aDrive : drivefiles) {
        rootpath = aDrive.getPath();
        Path directory = Paths.get(rootpath);
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory)) {   
          for (Path dir : stream) {
            int pos = dir.getFileName().toString().indexOf('$');
            File file = new File(rootpath + dir.getFileName());
            if ( (pos < 0) && (file.isDirectory()) ){
              srcdirlist.add(rootpath + dir.getFileName().toString());
            }
          }
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
      }
    }
    return srcdirlist;
  }
  
  /**
   * Get the number of drives discovered by iterating through the source directory paths
   * @param srcdirlist A list of paths to the directories that are to be copied.
   * @return The number of drives discovered.
   */
  private int getDriveCount(ObservableList<String> srcdirlist) {
    String driveletter = "";
    int drivecount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < srcdirlist.size(); i++) {
      if ( !(driveletter.equals(srcdirlist.get(i).substring(0,2))) ) {
        driveletter = srcdirlist.get(i).substring(0,2);
        drivecount++;
      }
    }
    return drivecount;
  }
  
 /** 
  * Initialize the directory letters array which uses the number of drives as its size. 
  * Then isolate each drive letter and assign it to the directory letters array. Note that
  * the result initially includes the drive selected as the destination drive, so this
  * has to be removed to avoid copying the contents of the drive being copied to itself.
  */
  private String [] getDirLetterArray(ObservableList<String> srcdirlist) {
    //Count the number of drive letters discovered
    int drivecount = getDriveCount(srcdirlist);
    String dirletters [] = new String[drivecount];
    String l = "*";
    int dn = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < srcdirlist.size(); i++) {
      if (srcdirlist.get(i).substring(0,3).equals(l)) {}
      else {
        dirletters[dn] = srcdirlist.get(i).substring(0,3);
        dn++;
        l = srcdirlist.get(i).substring(0,3);
      }
    }
    return dirletters;
  }
}

